# How to avoid JMeter recording server name or IP in each HTTP Request node?

Tags: jmeter

I tried creating a test plan as explained [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). But the only problem I am facing is each HTTP request recording the ServerName or IP, so if I change the server name from "HTTP Request Defaults", all HTTP request is not getting modified. Are there any ways to over come this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the future, create the "HTTP REQUEST DEFAULT" item BEFORE RECORDING, and fill in your server name and protocol into the Default Request.  This will keep the domain from being populated in every recorded request.

Answer (score 1):

When you add each `HTTP Request Sampler` to the Thread Group, you can leave the `Server Name or IP` and `Port` fields blank. It will take these from the `HTTP Request Defaults`

If these were filled from recording, then the only way is to delete them from each sampler screen of the recorded jmx

Comment: You can also open the JMX file in a text editor and do a "find replace all" to clean up your script if you have a lot of requests.  Create a back up file first.